# angularJS bind to input's enter key and submit if input is button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have such directive, to go to next input (or button) in modal window:

```
.directive('autoVrm', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var counter = 0;
            element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                console.log(element);           
                if(event.which === 13) {
                        counter++;
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var elementToFocus = element.find('input')[counter] || element.find('button')[1];
                    console.log(elementToFocus.type);
                    if(angular.isDefined(elementToFocus))
                        elementToFocus.focus();
                    if (elementToFocus.type === 'button'){
                        counter = -1;
                        elementToFocus.bind("keydown keypress", function (eventSubmit) {
                            if(eventSubmit.which === 13) {
                                console.log('submit');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

but i have one trouble, if i'm on button, and click enter i get:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

but why? how to make enter click to submit form? without dependency to controller?

Comment: please provide a fiddle on your problem. plus, check this error in the firefox console, it will tell you which function is undefined.

Comment: @camden_kid elementToFocus.bind("keydown keypress", function (eventSubmit) {

Comment: @DonJuwe via permissions i could not do that... (fiddle)

Comment: @camden_kid if i do console.log with this var i get: <button type="button" class="btn-md btn-green" data-ng-click="registerUser()">Register</button>

Comment: try `.on("keydown keypress", ...)` instead of `.bind("keydown keypress", ...)`

Comment: @DonJuwe no, it think that my elementToFocus is undefined

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: @camden_kid `console.log(elementToFocus);` gives me: `<button type="button" class="btn-md btn-green" data-ng-click="registerUser()">Register</button>`

Comment: @camden_kid yes, good idea... also: how to fire there data-ng-click="registerUser()" this?

Comment: @camden_kid but from controller... only fire controller's method... also write answer i will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try angular.element(elementToFocus).bind for the Uncaught TypeError.

Regarding your new comment:

If this is defined in your controller

```
$scope.registerUser = function() {
    ...
}
```

Then call it in the directive simply by

```
elementToFocus.bind("keydown keypress", function (eventSubmit) {
    if(eventSubmit.which === 13) {
        scope.registerUser();
    }
});
```

As a guess, you could do something like check the **attrs** parameter to get the value of 'data-ng-click' and call the appropriate function:

```
elementToFocus.bind("keydown keypress", function (eventSubmit) {
    if(eventSubmit.which === 13) {
        if (attrs.dataNgClick == "registerUser()" {
            scope.registerUser();
        }
        else if (attrs.dataNgClick == "sign()" {
            scope.sign();
        }
        else if (attrs.dataNgClick == "frgtPassword()" {
            scope.frgtPassword();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: see: in view i have `<button type="button" class="btn-md btn-green" data-ng-click="registerUser()">Register</button>` and if i write: `scope.registerUser = function() {
    ...
}` it will run directive's method, not controllers

Comment: can't you define the function in the controller? - it's allredy there, just how to call it from directive?

Comment: ng-click is not equal to enter key

Comment: i mean to not hardcode if in directive, but get from ng-click="what is here"

Comment: like `<button type="button" data-ng-click="registerUser()">Register</button>`, `<button type="button"  data-ng-click="sign()">sign in</button>`, `<button type="button"data-ng-click="frgtPassword()">frgtPwd</button>`

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I've edited my answer but I'm not sure it answers your question. I would like to help though if you can give me any more details.

Comment: dataNgClick  - this is undefined

Comment: all idea - you are right, just that attr are empty for button

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Is it possible to put modal-auto-focus on the button rather than the top level div?

Comment: to put yes, just how to be with inputs, if i have many modals at one page?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 I think I've run out of ideas unfortunately. One thing I would suggest is try to think of a different way of doing this. AngularJS has many ways of doing the same thing. Also, you may want to delete some of the comments on this page. Good luck and if I have any more thoughts I'll come back to this.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is already defined in web technologies. When you press ENTER inside a form, it is submitted. To achieve this, you need to handle the right event (ng-submit). You can achieve the effect you're looking for with less code.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function () {
  var self = this;
  self.message = "press ENTER to submit"; 
  self.count = 0; 
  this.onSubmit = function () {
    self.count++;
    self.message = "form submitted " + self.count + " times";
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <h1>Hello Stack Overflow!</h1>
    <form ng-submit="ctrl.onSubmit()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="press ENTER"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="press ENTER"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <div>{{ctrl.message}}</div>
  </body>

</html>
```